# Type name does not correspond to file name?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, warnings

This warning message is popped up when my mouse is over my class name, I can understand that the file name should be named exactly as the class name (or vice-versa) (which is defined in the cs file). That will be OK and of course good to follow but what if I intend to define more 1 class in a cs file? Or I shouldn't do like that?

I don't like any warning message, it seems to mean that I'm doing thing abnormally and in a non-standard way.

Comment: It improve readability and simplify working with types.

Comment: there you go http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53088/multiple-classes-in-a-single-cs-file-good-or-bad

Comment: Ok, this doesn't seem like a standard MS error. Are you using CodeRush? If so, their docs explain it : http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument10193

Comment: What I want is to know if it is OK to include 2 classes in 1 file, I can understand that if the class is so large/long, I should place it in 1 file only. But my case is 2 classes are only about 2 pages of code at all (about 30-40 lines), is it necessary to separate them into 2 files? The solution for long classes would be using partial keyword for declaring classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As comments point out it is not comment put by C# compiler (or Visual Studio).

There is no restrictions in C# on number of classes per file or if class/namespace should match file/folder name (unlike Java or ActionScript).

It is considered good practice to have one class per file (not counting nested classes) and somewhat match folder names to namespaces. This makes code easier to search and easier to find files corresponding to particular classes.

As for length of classes again there is no technical restriction, but long classes generally mean too many responsibilities in one class and as result not recommended. Generally there is no reason not to have many small classes in individual files.

You need to come up with style that works for you/people you work with and try to stay with it. Most code analysis/style checking tools (like ReSharper) are very flexible in style checking, so you often can adjust rules to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The first class in the file should be named same as the filename. If you need other classes that are only used by this class you can put them below this top level class and you will not get any warnings.